# Summarizing dataframe into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like such

```
    date        hour  level
0  2015-10-27    0     2.5
1  2015-10-27    1     2.5     
2  2015-10-27    2     2.5
3  2015-10-27    3     2.5
4  2015-10-28    0     0.0
5  2015-10-28    1     0.0
6  2015-10-28    2     0.0
7  2015-10-28    3     0.0
8  2015-10-28    4     0.0
...
14 2015-10-29    0     3.23
15 2015-10-29    1     3.23
...
```

`hour` will always begin at 0, and increment by 1; it may or may not reach 23. `date` is incremented one day at a time, but the number of date entries may vary from date to date, e.g. - `2015-10-27` has 4 entries, while `2015-10-28` goes up to row 13. The `level` entry will always have the same value for that date, but that value may or may not appear for another date.

What I'm trying to get is a dictionary of this form

```
{'2015-10-27': '3', ..., '2015-10-29': '4', ...}
```

The dictionary value indicates the range which `level` falls in, i.e. if `level` is 2.5, then it falls in [2, 3). What I was thinking of doing was just selecting the first row of each "block" and creating a new data frame, then iterating through that and applying 10 if statements (the max value for level is 9.xx) or possibly using a ceiling function. But I don't know how to do that either, and it seems quite clumsy.

Is there a more streamlined approach to doing this?

Comment: use `DataFrame.groupby`!

Comment: @AlanH Can you please explain more clearly what you are trying? You want the upper bound of `level` for each `date`? What if same date has multiple levels (from different ranges) ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar That doesn't occur in my dataframe, which is why I made the example with all the same level entries for each grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the values for `level` for each date would be in the same range, you can group based on `date` (using `DataFrame.groupby()` ) and then take `max` for `level` column and then ceil all the values (to the upper bound) , and then convert that series to dictionary using `Series.to_dict()` . Example -

```
df.groupby('date')['level'].first().apply(np.ceil).to_dict()
```

Demo -

```
In [44]: df
Out[44]:
          date  hour  level
0   2015-10-27     0   2.50
1   2015-10-27     1   2.50
2   2015-10-27     2   2.50
3   2015-10-27     3   2.50
4   2015-10-28     0   0.00
5   2015-10-28     1   0.00
6   2015-10-28     2   0.00
7   2015-10-28     3   0.00
8   2015-10-28     4   0.00
14  2015-10-29     0   3.23
15  2015-10-29     1   3.23

In [45]: df.groupby('date')['level'].first().apply(np.ceil).to_dict()
Out[45]: {'2015-10-27': 3.0, '2015-10-28': 0.0, '2015-10-29': 4.0}
```

---

If you want the values in your dictionary as `int` , you can convert the values to `int` before converting to dictionary using `Series.astype()` method. Example -

```
In [46]: df.groupby('date')['level'].first().apply(np.ceil).astype(int).to_dict()
Out[46]: {'2015-10-27': 3, '2015-10-28': 0, '2015-10-29': 4}
```

Comment: But what if I just wanted to represent the actual value? For example, for the key `'2015-10-29'`, instead of having `4` (as in your solution), I just wanted to `3.23` as the value.

Comment: remove the `.apply(np.ceil)` . From the above solution

Comment: How does leaving `min()` in there work? I don't understand what `df.groupby('date')['level']` looks like then (I can't print it).

Comment: You can use `.first()` instead of `min()` or `max()` . Its used simply to get one value for each group (each date) .